# What's aec and aer in SQL query?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, db2

I'm trying to understand what does `aec` and `aer` do in a SQL Query

For ex:

```
SELECT * FROM schema1.tablename1 aec
 

SELECT * FROM schema1.tablename2 aer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a look at the "alias" concept: https://www.db2tutorial.com/db2-basics/db2-alias/

When you use (and it's the same for the second query):

```
SELECT * FROM schema1.tablename1 aec
```

What you actually mean is that from there on you are referring to schema1.tablename1 as "aec", so you could do for example the following:

```
SELECT aec.* FROM schema1.tablename1 aec
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think, there is no particular sql query commands as "aec" and "aer"
from your code I can understand that query line:1

```
SELECT * FROM schema1.tablename1 aec
```

refers the tablename1 as "aec"; similar to "alias"

and same for the line:2

```
SELECT aec.* FROM schema1.tablename1 aec
```

refers the tablename1 again with "aec"; similar to "alias"

Hope it helps, don't stop you own research until it satisfies you :)